# flycheck: c/c++: how to pass the option --library=posix to cppcheck

Tags: flycheck

I found a lot of things to customize in flycheck, but not one that would enable passing down --library=posix option to cppcheck.

Comment: I can of course write a wrapper for cppcheck which injects that option, and point the cppcheck executable to the wrapper, but that would feel like a dirty hack.

Comment: If none internal variables in flycheck specify what you need, maybe try some of them - e.g. ```flycheck-cppcheck-standards``` in the form ```"--std=posix", "--library-posix"```.

Comment: The flycheck-cppcheck-standards seems to be a list of C/C++ standards, e.g. `(setq flycheck-cppcheck-standards '("c++20"))` and will end up as the cppcheck  `--std=` arguments, whereas the `posix`for the `--library=` means the POSIX standard C APIs, as opposed to the builtin setting for library which only includes the C standard APIs.